# Get Bootstrap theme into React app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, themes

I have a bootstrap theme with many CSS files. It is responsive and I want all the current styling for UI elements. However, I want to build my app out as React components only, What is the most efficient way to do this? How can I use the bootstrap theme's CSS files while recreating it in React?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches,

1. From index.html you can import the bootstrap.css file. You know, good old link attribute.
2. Use the styles on a component by component basis. You need something like [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-stylesheet)

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import './Button.css'; // Tell Webpack that Button.js uses these styles

   class Button extends Component {
     render() {
       // You can use them as regular CSS styles
       return <div className="Button" />;
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can just install Bootstrap  via npm/yarn:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Then you have to import Bootstrap in your top-level React file (the entry point):

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' // optional
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

You'll need the appropriate Webpack rules to transform CSS, of course.